# I need a fake hit or fake download counter for a blogger blog

Tags: php, download

Please i am searching for a fake download counter for my blog or a fake hit counter. that i can use multiple times on diffrent pages.

Here is what i am asking for, example immeditely after posting it

Post title 
Justin Bieber

Post Body 
blah, blah

Download: 3

REFRESH

Post title 
Justin Bieber

Post Body 
blah, blah

Download: 7

REFRESH

Post title 
Justin Bieber

Post Body 
blah, blah

Download: 12

Thats what i am looking for, please can someone share the code for me

Comment: `if ($post_title == 'Justin Bieber') { echo 'who cares'; } else { echo mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX); }` though perhaps honesty should still have some meaning in the world

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$filename = 'path/to/counter.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, "w+");
$i = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
$i = $i+5;
fwrite($fp, $i);
fclose($fp);
echo "Downloads: ".number_format($i);
?>
```

There you go.. try to be a little bit more HQ with your posts though.

Comment: Why both `file_get_Contents` and `fopen`?

Comment: fixed it, just realized it. thanks dude

Comment: sorry, i didnt mention i need it on a blogger blog. will this work on blogger blogspot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a cookie. Like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['counter'])) {
    $value = $_COOKIE['counter'] + 4;
    setcookie("counter", $value, time()+3600);
} else {
    $value = "3";
    setcookie("counter", $value, time()+3600);
}

echo $_COOKIE['counter'];
```

Hope this works for you. Here's an online example, just uploaded for you: http://inspirad.com/test.php

Comment: i dont want it to be cookies. i want it that even 10 diffrent people check the download button on diffent pc, so it will work per second, it will have the same download count... cookies will work for only one pc... thanks for the cookies. thou. will save it might come in handy later, but thats not what i want